# Bootstrap modal from hidden block

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have some code like bootrstrap example:

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div class="hider">
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
.hider {
  display: none;
}
```

But my modal doesn' work. Modal must be in block with display:none;
Please help me

UPD added demo http://jsfiddle.net/r7ahmcu9/

UPD2 My modal is in block that hides in mobile version, i can't delete display: none from hider

Comment: did not get your question

Comment: Then i click on Launch demo modal that shows only backdrop, but modal window is not visible

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/r7ahmcu9/ please read my comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply show / hide the block upon show / hide events :

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
 $(this).parent().show();
})
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
 $(this).parent().hide();
})
```

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/1o7sd2sj/**

BTW: You do realize that you are using Bootstrap 2.3.1 (!!??) in the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

ok as you said you can rid of from 'display: none;`then put modal html outside the`hider` class.

**eg:** you can put modal's HTML in beginning of the body. it will work when it called

**DEMO** https://jsfiddle.net/princesodhi/j5pan9hy/

**Note:** I checked you are a fiddle. which is using a really old version of Bootstrap

Comment: i can't do it, my block must be hidden

Comment: so does it help ?